# Color Coding Cells in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to color code cells in tableau on a particular column based on values from other columns. Is that possible ? 
Generally, I use conditional formatting on Excel to do this (Please see the attached spread sheet). But, wanted to find out if there is a tableau way of achieving this, this helps me automate my report.

So, from the below example, Goal_diff_measure1 cells are color coded based on corresponding values from pct_diff_measure1

logic :

```
pct_diff_measure1> 0 and pct_diff_measure1 <=10, yellow
pct_diff_measure1 >10, red
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible but needs a bit of hardwork to do.

Your logic will only color the font but not back ground so try below process.

Instead of using cross tab you need to use columns one by one so that we can manipulate the background colour effectively.

Giving example for one column this you can extend to any number of columns:

Create a calculated field and place `0` and save as Column1.

Place column1 on columns part and then place the `pct_diff_measure1` on label of marks of column1.

Replicate the same column 1 to the side of first column and then change the chart type to square, Then in marks increase the size of square to maximum.

Now create a dual axis which will combine square and value

Push marks to front and square to back

Write the conditional formula for colour and place on colour of square.

Repeat the same to all columns.